# При входе в адмику joomla выводит ошибку

Tags: php, sql, joomla

Скачал joomla сейчас с офииального сайта https://www.joomla.org/download.html. Установил, все правильно заполнил, вот только при входе в админку выдает такую ошибку.
[image: Скрин]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: смторите логи жумлы и php, формулировка `произошла ошибка` как те не очень подходит для определения что произошло.

Comment: @Naumov В папке /logs нету логов

Comment: @Naumov Я тестирую на денвере, как можно посмотреть логи php?

Comment: а joomla настроена на отображение ошибок http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-basics/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-joomla-25 есть небольшой мануал как настроить

Comment: @Naumov включил отображения ошибок в максимум, но никакого эффекта